# Control for subtitles selection in tvOS

Tags: avplayer, tvos, subtitle, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm looking for control (or somekind template) which is used for displaying subtitles selection in AVPlayer, exactly like on picture below 
[image]

I'd like to use the same control for quality selection. I've already all data and I've added custom controller to avplayercontroller for that purpose and it'll be nice, to use the same look&experience for that topic also.

Does anyone know, if there is something ready for use? Or should I recreate this using UICollectionView or UISegmentedControl?

P.S. I'm using storyboards for a development.

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t possible, you only can add more info to Info view. In my experience, I had to implement a custom view.

ref.: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19493#61400

Comment: Actually there is an option for adding a custom ViewController which will be available as a tab. I was able to do that. I was looking only for implementation of this control which is used for subtitles:)